# Toast Won't show on android application, using android studio

Tags: java, android

Good Morning, I tried getting the toast to show if the number of students is less than 0, or greater than 100. The app seems to work fine, except showing the toast. This assignment is due tomorrow night.

Here is my code:

```
package co.tekitall.classroommanager;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import static co.tekitall.classroommanager.R.id.NumOfStudents;

  public class Classroom extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_classroom);
      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitClassRoomInfoButton);

    }

    void ClassroomElements() {
      //ArrayList
      ArrayList<EditText> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
      arrayList.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Teacher_Name));
      arrayList.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Room_Number));
      arrayList.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ClassroomHelper));
      arrayList.add((EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumOfStudents));
    }

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText numofstudents = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumOfStudents);
        String getstucount = numofstudents.getText().toString();

        int setstucount = Integer.parseInt(getstucount);

        if(setstucount < 0) {

          numofstudents.setText("");
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Classroom.this, "Please try Again! Number must be greater then 0 and less than 100...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.show();

        }

        if(setstucount > 100) {

          numofstudents.setText("");
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Classroom.this, "Please try Again! Number must be greater then 0 and less than 100...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.show();

        } else
          numofstudents.setText("");
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Classroom.this, "Good Job", 
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.show();
        }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind `button` and listener using

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_classroom);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitClassRoomInfoButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Plus use `if` and `else-if` instead of multiple `if`s because a number can only be either less than `0` otherwise greater than 100 or between|equals 0 or 100

```
if(setstucount < 0){//...code}
else if(setstucount > 100){//...code}
else  {//...code}
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help , just for future reference `ClassroomElements()` method is doing nothing , the scope of `list` is only within this function , doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a `Button` and an `OnClickListener` but you're never connecting them together. For example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```